# Focus out of a div but not if a div was pressed - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a unique situation here that I am trying to figure out.  Here is what I am doing:

```
     $( ".add-user-group" )
      .focusout(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().find(".search-overhang").hide();
      })
      .focus(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".search-overhang").show();
      });
```

I am listening for when this input is selected to show a results container that is populated with a server call using `ajax`  Now within that `ajax` call I am populating data using:

```
               dataSent.parent().find(".search-overhang").html('');
                for(var i = 0; i < data.data_retrieved.length; i++)
                {
                    dataSent.parent().find(".search-overhang").append("<span class='overhang-data'><span>"+data.data_retrieved[i].display_name+"</span><br/><span class='bottom-inside-overhang-data'>"+data.data_retrieved[i].user_email+"</span></span>");

                }
                $(".overhang-data").on('click',function(event){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });
```

Now you will notice I have a `on click` that should override the `focusout` on the `add-user-group`.  But this is not the case.  Before it has a chance to do so it stops because I stop the event action using the `focusout`.  What I am trying to figure out is how can I override this, even with my data being dynamically populated?  Note one thing:  `add-user-group` is loaded server side before page loads.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After looking further I found a quick solution:

```
var clicked = '';
$(document).on('mousedown',function(event){
    clicked = $(event.target).attr("class");
});
..
.focusout(function(event) {
        if(clicked !== "overhang-data")
        {
            $(this).parent().find(".search-overhang").hide();
        }
})..
```

I am just listening on a global scale for what is clicked and storing that into a variable so when I need to check on the `focusout` I can verify if it is the corresponding class.